# Clustering plot. Add the cluster number: Function fviz_cluster (factoextra)

Tags: r, ggplot2, cluster-analysis, k-means, factoextra

I have the following R code:

```
library(factoextra)

kms<-kmeans(df,18,nstart=100)

fviz_cluster(kms, data = df, alpha=0.2,shape=19,geom = "point")
```

It outputs the following picture:

[image]

Is possible to add the number of the clusters inside the respective cluster in the picture?. Or show the cluster numbers instead fo the point centers.

**UPDATE.**

Something similar to I want to achieve I found in : https://www.r-bloggers.com/2016/11/hybrid-hierarchical-k-means-clustering-for-optimizing-clustering-outputs-unsupervised-machine-learning/

I tried it, but I got error. So I have to install the version of factoextra that is used and change the code. So I got this:

```
fviz_cluster(kms, data = df,frame.level = 0.68)
```

[image]

How can i remove the numbers except the numbers on the center of the cluster?

Answer (score 4):

There doesn't seem to be a simple solution; here is a potential workaround:

```
library(tidyverse)
library(factoextra)

data("iris")

# Select a single point for each category (i.e. setosa = the 25th value)
# label the selected value, then label the rest of the points with nothing ("")
iris$label <- c(rep("", 24), "setosa", rep("", 25),
                    rep("", 23), "versicolor", rep("", 26),
                    rep("", 24), "virginica", rep("", 25))


# Remove species column (5) and label column and scale the data
iris.scaled <- scale(iris[, -c(5,6)])

# K-means clustering
km.res <- kmeans(iris.scaled, 3, nstart = 10)

# Visualize clusters
fviz_cluster(km.res, iris[, -c(5,6)], alpha = 0.2, shape = 19, geom = c("point")) +
# Label the points (only the 3 with actual labels show up on the plot)
  geom_text(aes(label = iris$label))
```

[image: example_1.png]