# How do I interpret results of fviz_cluster() in r?

Tags: r, cluster-analysis, k-means

I'm running a model that checks the geopolitical patterns in different regions with respect to corporate tax rates, fiscal balance and tax revenue as % of GDP. For this, I want to use cluster analysis but I can't interpret the results. How do I figure out what each of the clusters stands for?

```
library(factoextra)
library(ggplot2)

#Check clusters by region 
ggplot(data = kmeans_basic_df, aes(y = Cluster)) +
  geom_bar(aes(fill = Region)) +
  ggtitle("Count of Clusters by Region") +
  theme(plot.title = element_text(hjust = 0.5))


# Visualise kmeans as clusters [What the clusters look like][1]
kmeans_vis<- kmeans(scale(data[,3:6]), 4, nstart = 100)
# plot the clusters
fviz_cluster(kmeans_vis, data = scale(data[,3:6]), geom = c("point"),ellipse.type = "euclid")


 


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/J30Jt.png
```

Comment: One potential option is to label a specific point in each group/cluster, e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/a/67067425/12957340

Comment: Greetings! Usually it is helpful to provide a minimally reproducible dataset for questions here. One way of doing this is by using the `dput` function. You can find out how to use it here: https://youtu.be/3EID3P1oisg